# Move cells into 1 row according to column A and Data and Time from Column D

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I think this photo should pretty much tell you what I am trying to achieve.

I can still try to explain bit.

I have on top table 5 column A B C D E

Column A is main it contains Num with record for individual numbers it can have up to 8 records.

I need to put all record in 1 line by NUM.

it is sort by A and D.

I just need to move column C based on time it occurred.

I just added extra column because I can have up to 8 Non Created and upto 4 Cause Created record.

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Manually, I was planning to write if else condition but didn't work `=IF(A2=A3,IF(MID(C2,1,FIND("Cause",C2,1)+4)="Cause",C2,""),"")`

Comment: Would you be filling the Col A manually in the 2nd table.

Comment: I don't want to manually fill Table2, if it can do it automatically by looking at Table1 that will save me many hours of manual work, I have over 800+ rows of data, can you please help me with this?

Comment: Is VBA An Option here?

Comment: Yes, VBA is ok. I am trying to like merge data into one row for each NUM and separate and sort column C according to timestamp(D).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24840/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-mowgli)

Comment: I can sort tablet1, however you like, I can either sort it by A then C then D or just A & D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the follwoing

1. The Table one is in Sheet called "Input"
2. The output will be generated in Sheet called "output" which already have the headers in place

Paste this code in a module and run it

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim wsILrow As Long, wsOLrow As Long, i As Long, c As Long, nc As Long
    Dim wsIrng As Range, fltrdRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim itm

    Set wsInput = Sheets("Input")
    Set wsOutput = Sheets("Output")

    With wsInput
        wsILrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set wsIrng = .Range("A1:E" & wsILrow)

        With wsIrng
            .Sort Key1:=.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Range("D2") _
            , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False _
            , Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:= _
            xlSortNormal
        End With

        For i = 2 To wsILrow
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value, Chr(34) & .Cells(i, 1).Value & Chr(34)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End With

    wsOLrow = 2

    With wsOutput
        For Each itm In col
            .Cells(wsOLrow, 1).Value = itm
            wsOLrow = wsOLrow + 1
        Next

        wsOLrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To wsOLrow
            With wsInput
                '~~> Remove any filters
                .AutoFilterMode = False

                With wsIrng '<~~ Filter, offset(to exclude headers)
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=wsOutput.Cells(i, 1).Value
                    Set fltrdRng = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                End With

                '~~> Remove any filters
                .AutoFilterMode = False
            End With

            '<~~ c is for Cause column and nc is for non cause
            c = 3: nc = 7

            For Each cl In fltrdRng.Cells
                If cl.Column = 3 And Len(Trim(cl.Value)) <> 0 Then
                    If InStr(1, cl.Value, "Cause", vbTextCompare) Then
                        .Cells(i, c).Value = wsInput.Cells(cl.Row, 3).Value
                        c = c + 1
                    ElseIf InStr(1, cl.Value, "Non", vbTextCompare) Then
                        .Cells(i, nc).Value = wsInput.Cells(cl.Row, 3).Value
                        nc = nc + 1
                    End If

                    .Cells(i, 2).Value = wsInput.Cells(cl.Row, 2).Value
                    .Cells(i, 15).Value = wsInput.Cells(cl.Row, 5).Value
                End If
            Next
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

Input Sheet

[image]

Output Sheet

[image]

**Note**: Any future changes to the structure has to be incorporated in the code as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm without any problem, you are life saver.